# Ultragrid infragistics excel export exporting UltraDropDownList ValueMember not DisplayMember

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am exporting an UltraGrid to Excel using Infragistics.Documents.Excel. The grid contains various columns one of which is of type DropDownList bound to a datasource. But when it is exported to Excel it displays the columns fine however the data in the excel field is the ValueMember for example 1,2,3,4 and not the DisplayMember for example 'Book'.  Does anyone know of a way around this?

Thanks,

Comment: I used the following workaround for this by populating another hidden column with the text value of this DropDownList and hiding the DropDownList column and just showing the Hidden text column before exporting the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the ExportedStarted event of the UltraGridExcelExporter component, where a copy of the UltraGrid's layout is created, get the ValueList that you are aware of and for each item set display member to the data value converted to string.

```
private void ultraGridExcelExporter1_ExportStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.ExportStartedEventArgs e)
{
        ValueList valueList = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[0].ValueList as ValueList;

        foreach (var item in valueList.ValueListItems)
        {
            item.DisplayText = item.DataValue.ToString();
        }
}
```